# Finding primary column in SQL Server table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql-server

[image]

I just created a SQL Server geometry columns table and a new table for testing in QGIS.  However, QGIS still won't find the primary column in the table.

I am creating the table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE gis.test (     OBJECTID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,     Name VARCHAR(255),      Shape GEOMETRY,     CONSTRAINT [qgis_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED    (       OBJECTID ASC    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]    )ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

And creating Geometry columns table this way:

```
  CREATE TABLE geometry_columns (
    [f_table_catalog] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [f_table_schema] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [f_table_name] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [f_geometry_column] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [coord_dimension] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [srid] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [geometry_type] [VARCHAR](30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT geometry_columns_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [f_table_catalog] ASC,
        [f_table_schema] ASC,
        [f_table_name] ASC,
        [f_geometry_column] asc
    )
) 

INSERT INTO geometry_columns (f_table_catalog, f_table_schema, f_table_name, f_geometry_column, coord_dimension, srid, geometry_type)
SELECT 
    g.f_table_catalog,
    g.f_table_schema,
    g.f_table_name,
    g.f_geometry_column,
    g.coord_dimension,
    g.srid,
    CASE WHEN g.geometry_type = 0 THEN 'Geometry'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 1 THEN 'point'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 2 THEN 'curve' 
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 3 THEN 'linestring'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 4 THEN 'surface'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 5 THEN 'polygon'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 6 THEN 'collection'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 7 THEN 'multipoint'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 8 THEN 'multicurve'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 9 THEN 'multilinestring'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 10 THEN 'multisurface'
         WHEN g.geometry_type = 11 THEN 'multipolygon'
    END AS geometry_type  
FROM 
    sde.sde_geometry_columns g
```

[image: SQL_import_error]

Comment: does SQL server see it? I haven't needed a geometry_columns table for QGIS to read sql server tables, including editing tasks...

Comment: Sql server sees it.  That's what's crazy about it.

Comment: Resolved.  Didn't use geometry columns table or checkbox.  Made the id field an int identity (1,1) primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Didn't use geometry columns table or checkbox. Made the id field an int identity (1,1) primary key.

Comment: ah yes! good stuff!